# Insert todays date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert today's date using NOW() into a MySQL database from PHP. I have tried various ways, but the query just produces a white page and does not insert any data into database.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. I have checked all fields and they are correct.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `act` (
    `slot`, `service`, `activity`, `department`,
    `company`, `address`, `user`, `item`,
    `date`, `new`)
VALUES (
    \''.$rack.'\', \''.$service.'\', \''.$activitys.'\', \''.$dept.'\',
    \''.$company.'\', \''.$address.'\', \''.$user.'\', \''.$v.'\',
    \'',"NOW()"'\', \''.$new.'\');';
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

Comment: Tried remove the quotes of NOW()?

Comment: If you used double quotes and/or [`sprintf()`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) you would save yourself a *lot* of trouble working with strings like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOW()` is an SQL statement and doesn't need any escaping. Remove the '"' near it

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the function `NOW()` and not the text `"NOW()"`. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Answer (score 1):

A clean query

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO act (slot, service, activity, department, company, address, user, item, date, new) VALUES ('.$rack.', '.$service.', '.$activitys.', '.$dept.', '.$company.', '.$address.', '.$user.', '.$v.', '.NOW().', '.$new.')';
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `act` (`slot`, `service`, `activity`, `department`, `company`,   `address`, `user`, `item`, `date`, `new`) 
VALUES (\''.$rack.'\', \''.$service.'\', \''.$activitys.'\', \''.$dept.'\', \''.$company.'\', \''.$address.'\', \''.$user.'\', \''.$v.'\', \'',NOW(), \''.$new.'\');';
```